# MySQL select timestamp as date string

Tags: sql, mysql, timestamp

I have a table with the column `create_time` which is of type `INTEGER` and represents the time since epoch.

I'd like to select all rows and columns, while displaying this row as a date/time in UTC format.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert seconds since epoch to a DATETIME, which also allows you specify a format:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(create_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```